# Working on a project with some others, I need to undo my friend's last 3 commits

Tags: git

My friend is working on one part of the project, and I am working on another part of it.

My friend just committed some code that was not code reviewed. I need to undo this. However, I don't want him to lose any of his work either.

Basically, I want to go back in time about 20 minutes - I want him to have all his changes on his machine but I want our master branch to NOT have these changes.

What's the best way of doing this? I'm concerned about doing a git reset --hard - I see that is permanent, and I'm concerned that doing that will erase the files on my friend's computer when he does a git pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, even if you do accidentally delete things permanently, Git by default keeps a record of removed items for a couple of weeks, so you can likely still recover. Note that this applies only to changes that have been committed or stashed at some point.

Second, the files won't be deleted when he does a pull if he moves his changes to a separate branch and doesn't checkout out remote on that branch. Or he just does a fetch and cherry picks changes.

Anyway, I haven't tried this personally, but I believe the command you want is

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

This will change the position of head to 3 commits ago while leaving the newer files in your working tree.

Comment: "by default". It keeps a record of the latest HEADs _by default_. No guarantees. And **only** if it has ever been committed (or stashed).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
git reset HEAD^^^
```

Add one `^` for each commit you want to undo.

Comment: didn't know about the `~X` syntax! awesome, tks :)

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is:

```
git log
```

Copy the checksum of the commit you want to go back to (for example  085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7), then perform a checkout. This will update your working tree with a version of the past.

```
git checkout 085bb3
```

You should now copy the working files to a different directory (you're currently not under a working tree).

Then go back to your master/main branch

```
git checkout master
```

Now you're back to your working tree.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend git revert for this. Revert will create a new commit that reverses the reverted commit. This means the original commit is intact, and also has the benefit of only removing the offending commit, instead of all commits that have happened since. So, if the commit you want to get rid of is xxxxx, you can just do this:

```
git revert xxxxx
```

By default, the commit message will tell others that it is a revert, and it will show the original commit id so everyone can easily find the reverted commit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.
`git branch not_code_reviewed_yet`.  This will create a branch with your friend's changes, so you can go back to them later.
`git reset --hard <commit you want master to go back to>`.  This should put master back to the commit before your friend's changes.  The version graph should now look like

```
A
 \-B-C-D
```

With A being master and D being `not_code_reviewed_yet`